# Renaming Rownames/Colnames of matrix `x` by matching column 1 in dataframe `y` and inserting column 3

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, r-rownames

I have two dataframes. One is a matrix with column and row titles, the other dataframe is the metadata of the matrix. The current row and column names of the matrix are accession numbers, but I have other names in the dataframe that I was to use in as the row/column names. The issue is that they are in different orders. I want to find the row in the metadata that matches the row/column in the matrix and change the row/column name of the matrix to the name matching a different column in the second dataframe.

Matrix:

```
             "XP01020938" "XP3943847" "XP39583574" "XP39384739"
"XP01020938"      1           0.5         0.25         0.1
"XP3943847"      0.5           1          0.5          0.25
"XP39583574"     0.25         0.5          1           0.1
"XP39384739"     0.1          0.25        0.1           1
```

Metadata:

```
Accession Name
XP3943847 Tiger
XP39583574 Elephant
XP39384739 Monkey
XP01020938 Horse
```

Desired:

```
          "Horse" "Tiger" "Elephant" "Monkey"
"Horse"      1      0.5      0.25       0.1
"Tiger"      0.5     1       0.5        0.25
"Elephant"   0.25   0.5       1         0.1
"Monkey"     0.1    0.25     0.1         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this using `match` ?

```
colnames(mat) <- metadata$Name[match(colnames(mat), metadata$Accession)]
rownames(mat) <- metadata$Name[match(rownames(mat), metadata$Accession)]

mat
#         Horse Tiger Elephant Monkey
#Horse     1.00  0.50     0.25    0.1
#Tiger     0.50  1.00     0.25    0.1
#Elephant  0.25  0.50     1.00    0.1
#Monkey    0.10  0.25     0.50    1.0
```

Comment: Oh my goodness yes thanks so much. I have not used R for a while and I completely forgot about the match function!